# How to convert a C++ struct variable to an LLVM Value*?

Tags: c++, llvm

I have the `StructType*` in LLVM for the struct type. Now I want to create a `Value*` type in LLVM from a struct variable in C++ and the `StructType*` variable. Are there any function in LLVM do this? Which API should I use?

Comment: Are you wanting to cast a value (i.e. struct variable) to that type?  Or do you need to allocate the variable of this type?  If you were writing C++ code, how would you want to allocate it (stack, heap, etc)?

Comment: Post the C++ equivalent of the struct/value idea you are expressing.